# ERROR at line 1:ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle

Hi I have the following table and I am running the follwoing query in it.

Table Name:MMC

Command that I am running is

```
SELECT REM_Q FROM MMC  where CLIENTQ = AJIT AND SENDER_SYSTEM = NEWYORK;
```

I am gettng the above error.
Can someone please tell me what is that I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5):

What columns are AJIT and SENDER_SYSTEM?  If they are `VARCHAR` then you should wrap parameters in quotes like `'AJIT'` and `'NEWYORK'`.

Comment: Just run `SELECT REM_Q FROM MMC  where CLIENTQ = 'AJIT' AND SENDER_SYSTEM = 'NEWYORK';`. Also I recommend reading some book about databases, this is honestly very basic stuff:)